# Pulls last 24 hours of logs and clean them python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, gzip

I have three file: 2 .gz files and 1 .log file. These files are pretty big. Below I have a sample copy of my original data. I want to extract the entries that correspond to the last 24 hours.

```
a.log.1.gz

2018/03/25-00:08:48.638553  508     7FF4A8F3D704     snononsonfvnosnovoosr
2018/03/25-10:08:48.985053 346K     7FE9D2D51706     ahelooa afoaona woom
2018/03/25-20:08:50.486601 1.5M     7FE9D3D41706     qojfcmqcacaeia
2018/03/25-24:08:50.980519  16K     7FE9BD1AF707     user: number is 93823004
2018/03/26-00:08:50.981908 1389     7FE9BDC2B707     user 7fb31ecfa700
2018/03/26-10:08:51.066967    0     7FE9BDC91700     Exit Status = 0x0
2018/03/26-15:08:51.066968    1     7FE9BDC91700     std:ZMD:

a.log.2.gz
2018/03/26-20:08:48.638553  508     7FF4A8F3D704     snononsonfvnosnovoosr
2018/03/26-24:08:48.985053 346K     7FE9D2D51706     ahelooa afoaona woom
2018/03/27-00:08:50.486601 1.5M     7FE9D3D41706     qojfcmqcacaeia
2018/03/27-10:08:50.980519  16K     7FE9BD1AF707     user: number is 93823004
2018/03/27-20:08:50.981908 1389     7FE9BDC2B707     user 7fb31ecfa700
2018/03/27-24:08:51.066967    0     7FE9BDC91700     Exit Status = 0x0
2018/03/28-00:08:51.066968    1     7FE9BDC91700     std:ZMD:

a.log
2018/03/28-10:08:48.638553  508     7FF4A8F3D704     snononsonfvnosnovoosr
2018/03/28-20:08:48.985053 346K     7FE9D2D51706     ahelooa afoaona woom

I am getting the below result but it is not cleaned.
result.txt
2018/03/27-20:08:50.981908 1389     7FE9BDC2B707     user 7fb31ecfa700
2018/03/27-24:08:51.066967    0     7FE9BDC91700     Exit Status = 0x0
2018/03/28-00:08:51.066968    1     7FE9BDC91700     std:ZMD:
2018/03/28-10:08:48.638553  508     7FF4A8F3D704     snononsonfvnosnovoosr
2018/03/28-20:08:48.985053 346K     7FE9D2D51706     ahelooa afoaona woom
```

Below code pulls the last 24 hours of line.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import glob
import gzip
from pathlib import Path
import shutil


def open_file(path):
    if Path(path).suffix == '.gz':
        return gzip.open(path, mode='rt', encoding='utf-8')
    else:
        return open(path, encoding='utf-8')


def parsed_entries(lines):
    for line in lines:
        yield line.split(' ', maxsplit=1)


def earlier():
    return (datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24)).strftime('%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S')


def get_files():
    return ['a.log'] + list(reversed(sorted(glob.glob('a.log.*'))))


output = open('output.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8')


files = get_files()


cutoff = earlier()


for i, path in enumerate(files):
    with open_file(path) as f:
        lines = parsed_entries(f)
        # Assumes that your files are not empty
        date, line = next(lines)
        if cutoff <= date:
            # Skip files that can just be appended to the output later
            continue
        for date, line in lines:
            if cutoff <= date:
                # We've reached the first entry of our file that should be
                # included
                output.write(line)
                break
        # Copies from the current position to the end of the file
        shutil.copyfileobj(f, output)
        break
else:
    # In case ALL the files are within the last 24 hours
    i = len(files)

for path in reversed(files[:i]):
    with open_file(path) as f:
        # Assumes that your files have trailing newlines.
        shutil.copyfileobj(f, output)

# Cleanup, it would get closed anyway when garbage collected or process exits.
output.close()
```

I want to use below function to clean the lines:

```
def _clean_logs(line):
    # noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    clean_line = clean_line.strip()
    clean_line = clean_line.lstrip('0123456789.- ')
    cleaned_log = " ".join(
        [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(clean_line)])
    cleaned_log = cleaned_log.replace('"', ' ')

    return cleaned_log
```

Now, I want to use the able clean function which will clean the dirty data. I am not sure how to use it while pulling the last 24 hours. I wanna make it memory efficient as well as fast.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the "make it memory efficient" part of your question, you can use the re module in stead of replace:

```
for line in lines:
line = re.sub('[T:-]', '', line)
```

This will reduce the complexity of your code and give better performance

Comment: Ok. And where I can call clean function while I process last 24 hours of data?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean where the function you created should be called? In this case you would want to wrap all your functions under  a def main() function at the end and call them from there.

Comment: If you see my big piece of code, I am using shutil.copyobj(), this copy the whole file to output if date is less than the current date. And my cleaning function works on lines. So, I can't use it on shutil.copyobj(). I want clean function to be called when my big piece of code pull last 24 hours of lines.